# General Expression for an Element of a Triangular Array

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

The [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) is formed by the following rules:

$i,j \in N^*$

$T(1,1) = 1$

$\forall j>i\;\;\; ; \;\;\;T(i,j) = 0$

$\forall i>1\;\;\; ; \;\;\;T(i,j) = T(i-1,j-1) + T(i-1,j)$

where $i$ is the row index and $j$ is the column index

---

There is a general formula for its non-null terms:

$T(i,j) = \left(\begin{array}{c}i\\j\end{array}\right) = \frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!}$

---

I would like to know if there is a general expression for the terms of the following triangular array:

$i,j \in N^*$

$T(1,1) = 1$

$\forall j>i\;\;\; ; \;\;\;T(i,j) = 0$

$\forall i>1\;\;\; ; \;\;\;T(i,j) = T(i-1,j-1) + j\;T(i-1,j)$

---

Here the five first rows:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0\\
1&3&1&0&0\\
1&7&6&1&0\\
1&15&25&10&1
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These number are ${i  \brace j}$, the *[Stirling numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)*. They are archived as *[A008277](http://oeis.org/A008277)* in OEIS.org.